# Argument function depends first argument

Tags: r, function

It is possible to attach a default value of arg2 who depends to arg1 ?

```
my_function <- function(arg1=df,
arg2=as.numeric(paste0(format(as.Date(max(df$myDate)),"%Y%m"),"01"))){

df2<-arg1[(arg1$myDate>=arg2),]
}
```

I don't have the same result when I attach his value in arg2 or in corps. For example :

```
 my_function <- function(arg1=df){

arg2=as.numeric(paste0(format(as.Date(max(df$myDate)),"%Y%m"),"01"))
df2<-arg1[(arg1$myDate>=arg2),]
}
```

Comment: Your second code snippet won't even run, I think, because the brackets aren't balanced.

Comment: where do you use `arg1` in your function?

Comment: Inside of a function exists a different namespace than outside. So please make sure that you take care of that and make a distinction. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Comment: @Cath `arg1=df`, so it is used as `df`

Comment: @stasg no, `df` is used as `df`, taken from global environment as it does not exist in function environment and `arg1`, the first argument of the function, which takes `df` value as default, is not used

Comment: @stasg the other way round is correct. Inside of the function `arg1` is supposed to be `df`, since df was assigned to it, or?

Comment: anyway `arg2` can be defined inside the scope of the function, based on `arg1`

Comment: @hannes101 indeed! my bad.

Comment: @Cath agreed. must be some namespace issues